# SQL syntax error in DELETE statement

Tags: vb.net

When executing a DELETE SQL statement i get an error message

> SYNTAX ERROR NEAR '*'

What could be the error in the following code ?

```
 Public Sub dele()

    Try
        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.10.3;Initial Catalog=IT_INV;user id=sa;password=1n@r1dev")

        con.Open()

        Dim inventtable As New DataTable("pc")
        Dim rs As New SqlCommand("DELETE * FROM pc WHERE [pcname]= '" & Label5.Text & "' ", con)

        rs.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted")

        con.Close()
        Display_Data()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please phrase your questions in the form of a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `*`, it doesn't belong to a `DELETE` but to a `SELECT`:

```
DELETE FROM pc ...
```

Also, always use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection and the `Using` statement.

```
Using con As New SqlConnection("Connectino string")
    Using rs As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM pc WHERE pcname=@pcname", con)
        rs.Parameters.Add("@pcname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label5.Text.Trim()
        con.Open()
        Dim deleted As Int32 = rs.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If deleted > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data Deleted")
        End If
    End Using '  connection doesn't need to be closed due to the Using
End Using
```